# CFG notation meaning in making LL parse table

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I have problem of interpreting Context-free grammar notation in making LL(1) parse table.

To make LL(1) parse table. Two rules are shown below:

1. If **A -> α** is a production choice, and there is a derivation **α =>* aβ**, where a is a token, then add **A -> α** to the table entry M[A,a].
2. if **A -> α** is a production choice and there are derivations **α =>* ε** and **S\$ =>* βAaγ**, where S is the start symbol and a is **a** token(or $), then add **A -> α** to the table entry M[A, a].

From the second theorem, I can't understand the meaning of **S\$ =>* βAaγ**.

I know the meaning of **S =>* βAaγ**, which means **start symbol** can be derived to **βAaγ**.

But what's the meaning of **S\$ =>* βAaγ** ? (The only difference is the existence of **$**)

Comment: What does your textbook say about it?

Comment: What do you understand the meaning of `α =>* aβ` to be? Note that `α` represents a sequence of grammar symbols, since it is the right-hand side of some production.